# rl_replace_line of readline library impossible to build on mac os

Tags: c, macos, makefile, readline, macos-big-sur

Recently I built a microshell program on Linux. I wanted to work on my MacBookPro (Big Sur 11.6.2) and found out that I'm having issue to compile my program because of the function rl_replace_line of the readline library.

I compile with :

```
clang -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I./includes
```

The error I'm having is :

> ```
> error: implicit declaration of function 'rl_replace_line' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
> ```

I found another question on stackoverflow and the answer was to compile with :

> -L .brew/opt/readline/lib and -I .brew/opt/readline/include

It doesn't work for me and I'm still having the same error. I tried what brew suggest which is to do :

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib" 
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include"
```

I also tried to compile with `-lreadline` and it doesn't work.

It still doesn't work for me.

Any idea what I could try to solve this issue ?

Thank you !

Comment: It means that in your source code you have not added an appropriate `#include` for the header file that contains the declaration of `rl_replace_line`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out several things until it suddenly worked. Key for me was to install readline with homebrew and then compile it with the other flags. My homebrew is in another folder than the one you mentioned. As I am a newbie I will post my entire makefile:

```
NAME ?= minishell
BONUS_NAME ?=

BUILD_DIR ?= ./objs
SRC_DIRS ?= ./srcs
INCL_DIR ?= ./include


LIB = libft-42
LIBS = $(addprefix -L ,$(LIB))

SRCS := $(filter-out %_bonus.c, $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name *.c))
OBJS := $(subst $(SRC_DIRS), $(BUILD_DIR), $(SRCS:.c=.o))

BONUS_SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name *_bonus.c)
BONUS_OBJS := $(subst $(SRC_DIRS), $(BUILD_DIR), $(BONUS_SRCS:.c=.o))

DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)

INC_DIRS := $(shell find $(INCL_DIR) -type d)
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))

CC = cc
CFLAGS ?= $(INC_FLAGS) -Wall -Werror -Wextra -MMD -MP -g
CPPFLAGS += -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include

LD = cc
LDFLAGS = $(LIBS) -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib
LINKS = -lft -lreadline

HIDE =

all: init_submodules $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    @make -C $(LIB)
    @echo "\nLinking:"
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LINKS)
    @echo "..\n"

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIRS)/%.c
    $(HIDE) mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(HIDE) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiling $< ..\n"

bonus: init_submodules $(BONUS_NAME)

$(BONUS_NAME): $(BONUS_OBJS)
    @make -C $(LIB)
    @echo "\nlinking bonus:"
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BONUS_NAME) $(BONUS_OBJS) $(LINKS)
    @echo "..\n"

$(BUILD_DIR)/%_bonus.o: $(SRC_DIRS)/%_bonus.c
    $(HIDE) mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(HIDE) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiling $< ...\n"

clean:
    $(HIDE) $(RM) -r $(BUILD_DIR)
    @echo "removing obj/ ..\n"

fclean: clean
    @make fclean -C $(LIB)
    $(HIDE) $(RM) $(NAME)
    $(HIDE) $(RM) $(BONUS_NAME)
    @echo "removing $(NAME) ..\n"

re: fclean all

init_submodules:
    git submodule update --init

.PHONY: clean fclean re all bonus init_submodules

-include $(DEPS)
```